# Bundle data stored in varible

Tags: java, android-studio, variables, bundle

I am working on a simple Android Studio app and I have a question regarding the process of saving information into a bundle in order to preserve it for the next instance when the activity is resumed (when the phone is waked up from sleep, more exactly). If I am going to say something wrong or I understood something wrong, please correct me.

So I saved a text view's text into a bundle in the *onSaveInstanceState* and "restored" it in *onRestoreInstanceState* method so that when I rotate the phone, the contents of the text view are not deleted and are preserved. Now, to save the appropriate text into the bundle I used a *final* variable (which I don't really understand why is supposed to be *final* if you store something from a bundle in it, even though it works both ways, but maybe there is an explanation for safety or something) like in the example bellow. I have some questions regarding everything:

1. If the variable would be *final*, and you store in it a hint to what should be saved later, then how can we later store the value of the text that we don't want to lose again since it is *final*? According to Wikipedia:

   > Once a final variable has been assigned, it always contains the same value. If a final variable holds a reference to an object, then the state of the object may be changed by operations on the object, but the variable always refer to the same object (this property of final is called non-transitivity).
2. What is the purpose of storing the value that we do not want to lose into a final variable?
3. (Most important) If all the variables are deleted after the execution of the program, then how can we store the value of something that we do not want to lose into something that is supposed to be deleted and still preserve the value?

P.S. I am taking an Android Studio course, and I really got stuck here and that is why I am asking.

```
package academy.learnprogramming.buttonclickapp;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.method.ScrollingMovementMethod;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText userInput;
    private TextView textView;
    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
    private final String TEXT_CONTENTS = "TextContents";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: in");

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        userInput = findViewById(R.id.editText);
        Button button = findViewById(R.id.button);
        textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);

        textView.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());

        View.OnClickListener ourOnClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String result = userInput.getText().toString();
                result += "\n";
                textView.append(result);
                userInput.setText("");
            }
        };
        button.setOnClickListener(ourOnClickListener);
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: out");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        Log.d(TAG, "onStart: in");
        super.onStart();
        Log.d(TAG, "onStart: out");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(@NonNull Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onRestoreInstanceState: in");
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        textView.setText(savedInstanceState.getString(TEXT_CONTENTS));
        Log.d(TAG, "onRestoreInstanceState: out");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestart() {
        Log.d(TAG, "onRestart: in");
        super.onRestart();
        Log.d(TAG, "onRestart: out");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        Log.d(TAG, "onResume: in");
        super.onResume();
        Log.d(TAG, "onResume: out");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        Log.d(TAG, "onPause: in");
        super.onPause();
        Log.d(TAG, "onPause: out");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onSaveInstanceState: in");
        outState.putString(TEXT_CONTENTS, textView.getText().toString());
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        Log.d(TAG, "onSaveInstanceState: out");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        Log.d(TAG, "onStop: in");
        super.onStop();
        Log.d(TAG, "onStop: out");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy: in");
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy: out");
    }
}
```

[image: Activity Life Cycle]